# kept getting this error: for name, home in reader: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, csv

kept getting

> ValueError: too many values to unpack(expected 2)

here's the csv file:

```
adebayo,sagamu sagamu, olomu 
yusuf,sagamu sagamu
kayode,sagamu sagamu
gbolahan,ilorin ilorin
abiodun,ilorin ilorin
```

```
import csv
students = []
with open("names.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for name, home in reader:
        students.append({"name": name, "home": home})

for student in sorted(students, key=lambda  student: student["name"]):
    print(f"{student['name']} is from {student['home']}")
```

Comment: Your first line has three items, not two.

Comment: You might want to use `csv.DictReader()`, it will create the dictionaries automatically. But you'll still have a problem if the number of fields is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your first line in csv file like this for it to work

adebayo,"sagamu sagamu, olomu"